# Can't get before pseudo element to work

Tags: css

I can't get the `::before` pseudo element to work in a drop down menu.

```
body.currency-gbp span.currency-symbol:before {
    content: "hi";
    width: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    background: red;
}
```

Yet, it works fine when I use the `::after` pseudo element

```
body.currency-gbp span.currency-symbol:after {
    content: "hi";
    width: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    background: red;
}
```

This is the basic HTML

```
<li class="level2 first"><a href="www.example.com"><span style="
">Under <span class="currency-symbol">50</span></span></a></li>
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Does the `body` have the class `currency-gbp`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, yes and it works with `:after`

Comment: just tested and both are working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/359jurvw/)

Comment: @Holy Looks like some other CSS rule is getting conflicted. We need to inspect the whole stuff. Can you replicate it in a snippet?

Comment: You should avoid child selectors and just use .currency-symbol as your selector. There's no need to specify the rest.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, you were right.  Thanks.  I went through the chrome inspector and at the very end of the list of CSS rules I saw the `::before` rule which was causing the conflict.

Comment: @Holy Awesome. Were you able to fix it? Shall I add as an answer and wanna accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like some other CSS is conflicting. You can go through the CSS Inheritance by inspecting the element's CSS history in Chrome's <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tools this way:

[image]

And this is how the styles get applied:

[image]
<sub>(source: [chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles-files/images/styles-annotated.png))</sub>

[image]

Comment: @Praveeen, thanks.  I added an image to your answer which  shows `::before` style listed at end of inspector.  May be useful for others too :)